# Sharepoint 2013 - what is the used masterpage for anonymous users?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

WHen I make any modifications in seattle.master, I see that all the authenticated users are able to see the changes. However, when I am an anonymous user, I do not see any changes, it seems like seattle.master is never used for anonymous users. The problem is I could not find which master page is used for anonymous users. I even tried to modify all the master pages in SP Designer 2013 one by one (Yea brute force:)), but nothing changed. Is there anyone that can give me a clue about this?

Thanks.

- SharePoint 2013 is used.

Comment: Have you published the new master page or just saved the changes? Check in the master page gallery.

Comment: I checked out the file, then edited the file, and finally checked in the file. I am checking http://myweb/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx, it is there and no checkout is seen.

Also, when I make any change on the page in SP Designer 2013 and click save, I can see the changes on the page when I do ctrl+f5 with an authorized user.

Comment: Generally you need to check in, publish and approve the master page file after a new version has been created. If you copen the context menu of your master page in your gallery, check if there are content approval options.

Comment: When I download a copy of the seattle.master from the gallery, I see the content is identical with the one I open in SP Designer.

Comment: Also, when I click the masterpage on gallery, then click files on the ribbon, it is writing "unpublish" and "approve/reject" there, but they are both not clickable.

I am SCA on the system by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I directed to the master page gallery myweb/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/allitems.aspx, then I checked out seattle.master, then immediately checked in. While checking in, I selected v3.0(publish). The problem is solved like that. Thanks @Serv for helping me to get the solution.